# JavaFX Get selected item of a ContextMenu?

Tags: java, javafx, contextmenu, actionevent

Since you can navigate a ContextMenu in JavaFX using the arrow keys, is there a way to retrieve the currently highlighted/selected MenuItem?

I'm basically trying to create an autocomplete feature like outlook etc does with email addresses, where you begin typing and it gives suggestions below, which you can press tab to input the selected menu action all without using the mouse.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'd probably try to implement this with a `ListView` inside a `Popup`. Then the standard selection model on the list view will give you what you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the selected menu item when you add an onAction listener to the context menu. The target of the ActionEvent is the selected menu item which you can further process.

```
    contextmenu.setOnAction(e -> System.out.printly(((MenuItem)e.getTarget()).getText()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a combo box instead. it gives you a drop down list and an optional text box. Context menu is a menu item and you can only implement a selection model if you wrap it in List view or table view.

Comment: Do you mean, for example, create a ListView and then use a new CustomMenuItem(ListView) to display the list? The problem I get with this is that I'd then require focus change from the TextField which isn't what I want. With a contextmenu I'm able to navigate it while still having focus on the TextField so continuing to type, if I wrap a ListView it's either focus the listview (requiring a click) OR the TextFIeld.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, context menu has limited event handling. You cannot listen for focus on menu item or the context menu itself. this makes it hard for the application to know which item is focused.

Comment: Is there no way to find this out by extending the class? Or by checking the style sheet to see if a MenuItem has a focused attribute?